# In S02E07 of The Witcher, where did the horses come from?

Tags: the-witcher

In S02E07, when Yennefer and Ciri flee from the attack in the temple, they end up in the house of some people who had helped Ciri previously. It seems that they find some horses directly outside the house, which they use to travel toward their destination.

The bodies of the previous inhabitants appeared to be in poor shape, and the battle of Sodden had occurred some months previously. Even assuming that the family had been wealthy enough to own *two* horses, they would not have been able to survive months tied up without food or water (in fact, they would likely have been unable to travel after about just a day without water). They could not have been Yennefer's, because she did not know that they would be going in that direction (they arrived via portal to a place Ciri felt safe, one that Yennefer did not know).

So whose horses were these, and where did they come from?

Answer (score 5):

When Yennefer looks at the bodies she says *”Fire Fucker”* implying that Rience had been there on his quest to track Ciri down and killed the family. From that we can infer that the family probably hadn’t been dead for very long.

From this we can tell that the horses belonged to the family. In the first season the dad who takes Geralt to the farm had two horses pulling his cart. The horses were different but that’s probably a “casting” issue rather than anything in universe.

Answer (score 0):

The family wasn't killed by Nilfgaard during the battle of Sodden, but much more recently by Rience ("fire fucker", the man who Yennefer disfigured by burning his face). This also happens in the books, though in the books Ciri and Yen don't visit. Instead it is told when Codringher is speaking with Geralt (*The Time of Contempt*, chapter 1):

> 'Rience showed up afterwards in Riverdell-'
> "I know,' interrupted Geralt. 'I know what he did to the Riverdell peasant family.'

As for where the horses came from, it's is either these very same horses from Season 1 Ep8 (see 0:28 into this [Youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5MTfIHBiqI), the ones before the cart, not Roach following behind it) or some other horses belonging to the family. In the season 2 episode you refer to, Yennefer is riding a brown horse and Ciri a white.

The merchant Yurga who Geralt saves is the husband of the woman who helps Ciri. They own a stable (as seen in the above clip) and several horses.

(I even think there is a brief scene where Ciri is helping out in the stable(?) but I can't find any pictures of that.)